# How do I add a Twig Filter?

Tags: 8

I made a custom module that extends TwigExtension, where I define all sort of custom twig filters. It worked well until the update to 8.3, where TwigExtension changed slightly:

```
/**
* Constructs \Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.
*
* @param \Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface $renderer
*   The renderer.
* @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGeneratorInterface $url_generator
*   The URL generator.
* @param \Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManagerInterface $theme_manager
*   The theme manager.
* @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter
*   The date formatter.
*/
public function __construct(RendererInterface $renderer, 
  UrlGeneratorInterface $url_generator, ThemeManagerInterface 
  $theme_manager, DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter) {
  $this->renderer = $renderer;
  $this->urlGenerator = $url_generator;
  $this->themeManager = $theme_manager;
  $this->dateFormatter = $date_formatter;
}
```

My service yaml looked like this:

```
services:
  custom_twig.twig.extension:
    arguments: ['@renderer']
class: Drupal\custom_twig\TwigExtension\LabTwigExtension
tags:
  - { name: twig.extension }
```

And I changed the services to have the new required ones.

```
services:
  custom_twig.twig.extension:
    arguments: ['@renderer', '@url_generator', '@theme.manager','@date.formatter']
class: Drupal\custom_twig\TwigExtension\LabTwigExtension
tags:
  - { name: twig.extension }
```

Although I set the correct arguments, Drupal throws an error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension::__construct() 
>       must implement interface Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGeneratorInterface, none given, called in /A

I am fairly certain that url_generator implement UrlGeneratorInterface. Is there anything else I got wrong?

Comment: Surprise!!! welcome to the new world of semantic versioning.

Comment: Without seeing the code of the constructor for your class, we cannot point you to the error. If I understand you correctly, you just show the constructor of the base class.

Comment: As side note, your class constructor should call the constructor of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Twig Extender](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extender) , try updating it to version 8.x-2.0-rc1. It worked for me